# Get selected value from datalist

Tags: vba, validation, excel

I have cell which has data validation drop-down list.

How to retrieve currently selected value in it?

For example there are: 1) cat 2) dog 3) hypo in the drop-down list and currently dog is selected, I need a code that will get the "dog" value , when something else is selected, I'll get it's value.

I've tried `cells(1,1).value range("A1").value` etc, didn't work.

The code is something like:

```
 Private Function Kne_mida_calc() As Double
   If Range("E16").Validation.Formula1 = "1:250" Then
        Kne_mida_calc = 1.3
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Cells(15, 5).Value = "1:500" Then
        Kne_mida_calc = 1.15
        Exit Function
        ElseIf Cells(15, 5).Value = "1:1250" Then
        Kne_mida_calc = 1
        Exit Function
     ElseIf Cells(15, 5).Value = "1:2500" Then
        Kne_mida_calc = 0.85
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Cells(15, 5).Value = "1:5000" Then
        Kne_mida_calc = 0.75
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Cells(15, 5).Value = "1:10000" Then
        Kne_mida_calc = 0.5
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @A.S.H I've posted what i'm trying to do, with two different options

Comment: try using .Text instead of .Value, just to see?

Comment: I've tried, I think I'l try to go with Com-Ins drop-down list instead of the data validation tool' since I haven't found validation object property to correspond for the value nor text property... :\

Comment: Something that puzzles me, how could you enter 1:500, 1:1500 etc in your validation range? Does it really display this as a string? Or does it convert it to a number??

Comment: I am almost sure that the trouble is in the special shape of the values. 1:500, this is unusual, and Excel converts it to a number unless you set the cells types to Text.

Comment: @A.S.H, I've checked, it was set on TEXT but I still can't get the values.. So I'll go another way around. Thanks for your help, once again!

Comment: If it's a data validation dropdinw, the selected item is the cell's value. What happens when you test that?

Comment: @Rory it provides blank vale. I have used ActiveX to do a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is code of the function:

```
Private Function Kne_mida_calc(scl As String)  
Select Case scl  
    Case "1:250"  
        Kne_mida_calc = 1.3  
        Exit Function  
    Case "1:500"  
        Kne_mida_calc = 1.15  
        Exit Function  
    Case "1:1250"  
        Kne_mida_calc = 1  
        Exit Function  
    Case "1:2500"  
        Kne_mida_calc = 0.85  
        Exit Function  
    Case "1:5000"  
        Kne_mida_calc = 0.75  
        Exit Function  
    Case "1:10000"  
        Kne_mida_calc = 0.5  
        Exit Function  
    Case Else  
        Kne_mida_calc = "Error!"  
        Exit Function  
End Select  
End Function
```

How to use function at worksheet:
Put your data validation in cell E16

Put this formula in another cell:
=Kne_mida_calc(E16)